# Make animation with box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I make simple game with libgdx. I want to add box2d physics engine. I have three sprites and one of them is animated (dynamic bodie). The rest are static. I don't know how to integrate this with box2d. Is there any solution. I spent a lot of hours for searched but found nothing.
My world renderer class:

```
public WorldRenderer(GameWorld world) {
    this.world = world;
    this.camera = new OrthographicCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    this.camera.position.set(CAMERA_WIDTH/2f, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2f, 0);
    this.camera.update();
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    loadTexture();
}

public void loadTexture() {
    TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("gfx/textures.atlas"));
    int indexr = 1;
    int indexl = 1;
    monkeyLeft = atlas.findRegion("left");
    monkeyRight = atlas.findRegion("right");
    platformTex = atlas.findRegion("platform");
    bananaTex = atlas.findRegion("banana");
    TextureRegion[] walkRightFrames = new TextureRegion[2];
    TextureRegion[] walkLeftFrames = new TextureRegion[2];
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        walkLeftFrames[i] = atlas.findRegion("left", indexl++);
        walkRightFrames[i] = atlas.findRegion("right", indexr++);
    }
    goLeft = new Animation(RFD, walkLeftFrames);
    goRight = new Animation(RFD, walkRightFrames);
}

public void render(){
    spriteBatch.begin();
    drawPlatform();
    drawMonkey();
    drawBanana();
    spriteBatch.end();

}

public void drawMonkey() {
    Monkey monkey = world.getMonkey();
    monkeyFrame = monkey.isFacingLeft() ? monkeyRight :  monkeyLeft;
    if(monkey.getState().equals(Stan.WALK)){
        monkeyFrame = monkey.isFacingLeft()? goLeft.getKeyFrame(monkey.getStateTime(), true) : goRight.getKeyFrame(monkey.getStateTime(), true);    
    }
    spriteBatch.draw(monkeyFrame, monkey.getPosition().x*ppuX, monkey.getPosition().y*ppuY, Monkey.SIZE*ppuX, Monkey.SIZE*ppuY);
    }

public void drawPlatform() {
    for(Platform platform : world.getPlatforms()){
        spriteBatch.draw(platformTex, platform.getPosition().x*ppuX, platform.getPosition().y*ppuY, Platform.SIZE*ppuX, Platform.SIZEH*ppuY);
    }

}
public void drawBanana() {
    Banana banana = world.getBanana();
    spriteBatch.draw(bananaTex, banana.getPosition().x*ppuX, banana.getPosition().y*ppuY, Banana.SIZE*ppuX, Banana.SIZE*ppuY);

}
```

Comment: Can you expand on the question a bit, because I do not understand what so ever what you are after. Maybe a short video would help. What the code relate to ?

Answer (score 1):

Create your [world](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World.html). Create your bodies, step your simulation. And render them using the width, height, body position and rotate angle like this:

```
batcher.draw(animkeyframe, body.getPosition().x-width/2F, body.getPosition().y-height/2F, width/2, height/2, width, height, 1, 1, MathUtils.radiansToDegrees*body.getAngle());
```

For more info about Box2d: [Wiki Entry](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d)

I can see most these things in your WorldRenderer code. Only stepping the simulation is not there.